# Showing more text with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a way to show more or less text. I want to show 600 characters by default and if show more is clicked it will show 600 more characters and then if clicked again shows 600 more until there are no more characters. I also would like a show less button to collapse the text back to its default 600 characters. I have pages with 5000+ words and this would make reading much easier and make it look nicer. Right now I am using this to show the first 600 chars and when show more is clicked it expands all the way.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var showChar = 600;
var ellipsestext = "...";
var moretext = "View more";
var lesstext = "View less";
$('.more').each(function() {
    var content = $(this).html();

    if(content.length > showChar) {

        var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
        var h = content.substr(showChar-1, content.length - showChar);

        var html = c + '<span class="moreelipses">'+ellipsestext+'</span>&nbsp;<span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><a rel="nofollow" href="" class="morelink">'+moretext+'</a></span>';

        $(this).html(html);
    }

});

$(".morelink").click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
        $(this).removeClass("less");
        $(this).html(moretext);
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("less");
        $(this).html(lesstext);
    }
    $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
    $(this).prev().toggle();
    return false;
});
});
```

Could somebody please edit this code to work like this or help me to achieve this any other way? I would really like to make my pages more presentable and readable and this would definitely do the trick. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like pagination is far more appropriate, and as a user, I would find this functionality kind of annoying, just my opinion though.

Comment: Well I would like it this way so I can show more content on a page and have several instances of the show more which would make things look nice. If it were for a single article on a page I could see it being annoying. I will look into pagination for this but I figured some sore of javascript or jquery with some sort of infinite loop or something on the text would work. I have never even seen a function like this before.

Comment: Won't this be incredibly slow? Anyway, why do it with characters? It would be much easier to do it with height of the box. You could just slide it to expand it every time. (and I kind of agree with the others, sounds like an odd solution. Content is king, don't hide it away)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I knocked up the following code to show you how to elicit information from the viewer concerning the number of lines:

The HTML:

```
<div style="height: 6em; overflow: auto; line-height: 1.5em">
    <p> Number of lines to display  (optional) <input type="text" value="4" style="width: 3em"><button type="button" class="scrollLength">change</button></p>
    <p>
        This is a huge load of text<br>
        line 2<br>
        line 3<br>
        line 4<br>
        ...etc....
    </p>
</div>
```

The jQuery code:

```
$('button.scrollLength').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.click(
        function(){
            var myParent      = $this.parent();
            var numberOfLines = myParent.children('input').attr('value');
            var displayArea    = myParent.parent();
            if (numberOfLines > 0) {
                var lineHeight  = displayArea.css('lineHeight');
                var heightUnits = lineHeight.replace(/[0-9]./g, '');
                displayArea.css({height: (numberOfLines * parseFloat(lineHeight)) + heightUnits});
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Regards
      Neil

Answer (score 1):

check out the following links -

http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/index.html#getting-started

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2010/12/dynamically-shortened-text-show-more-link-jquery.html

http://shakenandstirredweb.com/240/jquery-moreless-text

Comment: I have actually seen all those articles. I have not seen an example that will keep letting you use show more after clicking the first time. That is what I am trying to achieve. I appreciate your effort in trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

Why do all this when you can do more or less what you want by putting the text in a div that has scrollbars. You don't need any javascript at all, just style it using CSS e.g.

```
<div style="height: 6em; overflow: auto; line-height: 1.5em">
    <p>
        This is a huge load of text<br>
        line 2<br>
        line 3<br>
        line 4<br>
        ...etc....
    </p>
</div>
```

Just set "height" (6em in the example above) to 1.5 times number of lines you want to display at any one time (e.g. for approximately 40 lines set "height: 60em").

This way you also handle the fact that the 600th character will almost certainly be in the middle of a word!

Regards
       Neil

Comment: Hi, when I say 1.5 times the number of lines, the 1.5 is the value of the "line-height". Obviously if "line-height" were 2, then you would need to specify the height as 2 times the number of lines. You could be nice and let the viewer specify the number of lines he/she want to see at a time in an "<input>" element and modify the CSS with jQuery accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for all your input I am sure I will figure something out now from what you have provided me. maybe I will go with putting the text in a div with scroll bar. Sounds pretty good and definitely the easiest and best way.